# How can I free a service provider from estimate liability via disclaimer?

Tags: united-states, california, business

I want to ask for a quote, but I don't want the service provider to be legally bound to the estimate. What should I disclaim in my quote request?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Why would you not want a formal estimate? The very term implies it's not exact so they are not bound by anything. DO you mean an offer?  You are not bound to accept their offer.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing to do is to just write "Non-Binding" on the quote itself or to stipulate same in the request for quote.

Either that, or you can write a complete sentence like what @jqning wrote:

> "*This quote is for informational purposes only and creates no obligations on the part of any party.*"

However, as @gracey209 commented, quotes alone *usually* do not create any binding obligations. Unless it's agreed by all parties in advance that it will. As in a formal bidding process. For example, if there were a closed bidding process for contract work, it might make sense for the bidders to be bound to their bid as a condition for having their bid considered.

However, that scenario does not seem match the circumstances you describe. If it did, then just leave out any binding language in the bid agreement.

Answer (score 0):

A request like the one you are talking about could
1. State that it is for informational purposes only and creates no obligations on the part of any party and
2. Free all parties from any existing obligations.